# duplicate/mirror git repository: invalid refspec

Tags: git, github, mirror

I am trying to duplicate a github repository following

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

and when I do:

```
git push --mirror https://github.com/myuser/new-repository.git
```

It says:

```
fatal: invalid refspec 'https://github.com/myuser/new-repository.git'
```

If I do:

```
git log refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I can see the last commits ...

What should I do to duplicate this repository?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it in another way
with https://github.com/new/import and set the old repository in the field.

The default master branch was replaced by another branch.
I just needed to set it has default again and
I have the duplicated project ready